# checking resources in xml and displaying icons for the resources in android

Tags: android

hai every one. i am new to android. in my project i had some problems reading xml files. In my xml i have included some audios and videos paths and i want to read the xml file  through the code  and i want to display some images n my view if there are some audio or video files. can any body tel how to read the xml file.
 thanking you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first you need to create a parser Below is the code to do this:

public static void readTemplateFile(Context context) {

```
    /**
     Include File Checking
     */

    try {
        XML_Handler_Template myExHan = new XML_Handler_Template();

        InputStreamReader isr =  new
        FileReader( new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Library Template.xml" ));

        XML_Handler_Template.context = context;

        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        xr.setContentHandler((ContentHandler) myExHan);

        xr.parse(new InputSource(isr));


    } catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(context, ">" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

}
```

You then need a Handler Class. In the above example my class is called XML_Handler_Template.

FileReader( new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/FILEPATH/FILE.XML" ));

Here is the XML_Handler_Class at the moment it is blank:

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class XML_Handler_Template extends DefaultHandler{

```
    public static Context context = null;

@Override
public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
    //this is called when the document is first read
}

@Override
public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
        String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
                    //This is called when a new Tag is opened
                    //localName holds the Tag Name, the Value is got from the 
                    //Characters function at the end of this class

                   //the attributes for each tag are stored in the atts array, you can either handle the attribute values here or pass the information to a separate function to handle them,
                   if (atts.getLength()>0){
            for (int i=0;i<atts.getLength();i++){

                addAttrib(atts.getLocalName(i) , atts.getValue(i))  ;

            }
        }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName)
throws SAXException {
    //This is called when a Tag is closed
}

@Override
public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
                //this is called when the document is closed
}

@Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
            //This is where the value of a Tag are read
    String value = new String( ch , start , length );
            // You may want to include a replaceAll("\r","") and replaceAll("\n","") to remove any hidden chars

}
```

}

have a play with this and see how you get on for now =0) I passed a context to the class so whilst i was learning I could use toasts to show me the values that were being read.

Comment: k thank you. i hav stored on SD card and i want to display the relevent audio\video icon.

Comment: Ok there are a couple of things you need to implement

Comment: Ok there are a number of things you need to get to grips with.

1. XML parsing
2. Drawables (The Icons and the specifications needed for different devices)
3. Views and inflators. Adding custom ListItems to a listView Or Dynamically adding views to a ScrollView

are you familiar with any of the above?

Comment: kk thank you. i know XML parsing but not have full grip over it.can u provide any links to grip over it or can u tel how to read the xml file

Comment: Ok, well there are a few different methods of XML parsing I only know how to use SAX I don't know if I'm allowed to post external links so I will and see if a Mod tells me other wise. http://www.anddev.org/parsing_xml_from_the_net_-_using_the_saxparser-t353.html